# Unable to click button inside table row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, html-table

The Edit/Delete buttons are unclickable when inside the table. (The mouse pointer doesn't change like usual either)

Anyone have a clue as to what's going on?

Here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/xt7spu41/

```
    <td class="report-elements report-tools">
            <button class="btn btn-default">Edit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </td>
```

Comment: you have a div  with class `table table-hover table-responsive table-striped main-panel` positioned absolutely over the buttons,you could try removing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `z-index: -1` from `.main-panel`.

Comment: @MightyRevenge Glad to help, as a general tip, when you can't click something it's usually z-index messing with you.

Answer (score 0):

Check fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nileshmahaja/xt7spu41/5/

I have modified below code into the provided Fiddle

```
/* Slide the table under the top nav bar */
.main-panel {
    margin-top: -2px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

> Changing Z-index makes to click through the buttons. this is because
>   the container which is containing buttons was behind the other elements previously.
>   after changing it's z-index to 1 makes main-panel div to come up and make the
>   buttons clickable